# always display 3 buttons in a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, button, horizontalscrollview, programmatically-created

[image: 3 buttons scrollview]

Hello everyone I am trying to display 3 to X buttons on android.
The idea is to always start with 3 buttons that takes each 33% of the size of the screen (width) And to be able to scroll **Horizontaly** through items.

Also theses items will be added programmatically to the view.

I tried to put a LinearLaout horizontal within an HorizontalScrollView. 
And then addchild to the linearlayout. but the items resize and it doesn't scroll.

Is it the right approach ? or does anyone have an idea how to make it ?

Class.java

```
HomeCircledButton button = HomeCircledButton_.build(this);
button.title.setText(sc.get(i).getLabel());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.33f));
homeButtonsLL.addView(button);
```

Layout.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="1.0"
                android:id="@+id/home_buttons_ll">
           </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I also tried to create the buttons already in the XML and hide them programatically (View.GONE) but they just resize

Comment: Seems to be proper approach. But if there are too many buttons it's better you go for `HorizontalListView` because of it's view reuse capability. As for the current approach, can you post some code where you are applying 33% logic and adding LinearLayout to scrollview?

Comment: just edited the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting the size dynamically and there are unknown number of child views, then `weight` approach isn't that feasible. Instead get the width of the screen, and based on that set the width of the button. Also,
`LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.33f));` this line in your code will not work as you expected. You need to set the params to button to make it work.

You can try something like this,

```
HomeCircledButton button = HomeCircledButton_.build(this);
button.title.setText(sc.get(i).getLabel());
//divide the screen width by 3
int buttonWidth = getScreenWidth() / 3;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonparams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
button.setLayoutParams(buttonparams);
homeButtonsLL.addView(button);
```

...

```
private int getScreenWidth( ) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        int width;
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
        .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        return width;
    }
```

and you don't have to set weight sum in xml,

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/home_buttons_ll">
           </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks you! i was looking too much into weight instead of playing with the width